# How do I bind a listbox to XPath of SelectedItem from another Listbox?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, xpath, binding

Here's the XML:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item1</Name>
        <Links>
            <Link>
                <LinkText>Image 1</LinkText>
                <LinkUri>Images/Image1.jpg</LinkUri>
            </Link>
            <Link>
                <LinkText>Image 2</LinkText>
                <LinkUri>Images/Image2.jpg</LinkUri>
            </Link>
        </Links>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item2</Name>
        <Links>
            <Link>
                <LinkText>Image 3</LinkText>
                <LinkUri>Images/Image3.jpg</LinkUri>
            </Link>
            <Link>
                <LinkText>Image 4</LinkText>
                <LinkUri>Images/Image4.jpg</LinkUri>
            </Link>
        </Links>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

Here's the binding for the first `ListBox`

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider
            x:Key="Items"
            Source="ScannerProblems.xml"
            XPath="Items" />            
</Grid.Resources>

<ListBox
                x:Name="lstProblems"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}, XPath=Item}"
                DisplayMemberPath="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border
                        Background="#2200FF00"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        Margin="2,4,2,4"
                        Padding="4">

                        <StackPanel
                            x:Name="sp">
                            <TextBlock
                                FontWeight="Bold">Problem Description</TextBlock>

                            <TextBlock
                                Width="{Binding ElementName=sp, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                Text="{Binding XPath=Name}"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter
                            Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
```

So from that `ListBox` I select an item.  When I select that item, I want to have another `ListBox` populated with the Link items from the XML for that selected item. It seems like it should be a piece of cake, but the different things I've tried give me either an empty `ListBox` or `System.Windows.DataTemplate` in the `ListBox` (only once, not a list of times).

**EDIT:** From here down, I've modified.  This is the markup for the second `ListBox` after making suggested changes.  Here is what it now looks like for those who use this question in the future:

```
<ListBox
            DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstProblems}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Links/Link}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}">
                        <Button.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image
                                        Margin="10"
                                        MaxHeight="200"
                                        Source="{Binding XPath=LinkUri}" />

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Text="{Binding XPath=LinkText}"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        Margin="10,0,10,20" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Button.ContentTemplate>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` should come under  `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` for the second list. Currently you  are setting it directly under it thats why you are seeing the class name.And since you are setting the `DataContext` directly with a collection, you will have to set `ItemsSource={Binding}`

Comment: Thanks.  That got me the binding on the TextBlock.  Now I can work at figuring out the binding of the image button in the commented out section.  Thanks!

Comment: are these images included in project?

Comment: Yes.  I've now gotten the images to work if I just put the images into the ListBox, or if the ListBox has an ItemTemplate of a StackPanel with an Image and a TextBlock in it.  But I'm stuck at taking that and turning it into a list of Buttons with an Image and a TextBlock within the Button.

Comment: ohh you have not set the Content of the button. Just do <Button DataContext="{Binding XPath=Link}" Content="{Binding}"
                    Margin="5">

Comment: Ok - I just edited the question with what does and doesn't work.  Now I'll add what you just commented, and see what that does.  Thanks!

Comment: Question modified to show the markup that worked, for those who refer to this question later.